# Cheap flight USA-Taiwan for Christmas

Tags: usa, budget, public-holidays, taiwan

I already watched the ticket prices for a San Francisco - Taiwan round trip (or from whatever city in the US) some monthes ago, especially for the christmas holiday, and it was already 1800 dollars at strict minimum, and today it is even more expensive...I've been looking on [bourse-des-voyages.com](http://www.bourse-des-voyages.com/) , which is usually a good site, but there is nothing for less that I found today, even by modifying the dates a lot. The question is, am I missing some option, or is it just that christmas transpacific travel is made for rich people?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it seems like you're not missing much. US to Taiwan appears to be surprisingly expensive.

I got 1264 euros on [momondo.com](http://momondo.com), 1764 USD on [Google's flight search](https://www.google.com/flights/) and 1525 USD on [matrix.itasoftware.com](http://matrix.itasoftware.com).

Comment: thank you very much for these links! I did not know Momondo.com, you actually get to see the approximative graph of prices of the go & go back flights. Usually you have these graphs on company-specific websites...here it's in a general view! Before that I had to go blind in the fog, trying each combination of days, cities, etc...thanks! I found 1200 euros on momondo, it is already 400 euros saved...